# Orion Skyquest xt8i Intelliscope Dobsonian Telescope Lens

Tags: telescope, orion

I have the telescope in the title, which camps with 10mm and 25mm eyepieces. Both cannot really see anything in detail past the moon. All planets look like stars. What are good eyepieces for seeing all the other planets in detail, respectively?

Comment: Where are you?  A location with significant humidity and / or turbulent winds might destroy the seeing enough to blur out planets.  A quick check would be to use 8x binoculars to observe the planets and see what details you can note.

Answer (score 7):

The telescope you have is quite well regarded, and the eyepieces that come with it are of reasonable quality.  If you can see the moon clearly, including craters and other features, then you should be able to see that the planets, particularly Jupiter and Saturn,  are not like stars.  At the very least they will look like disks, not points of light, and saturn's rings will be unmistakable. The 10mm lens will give magnification of 120, which is more than adequate.  My guess is that you are not looking at the planets, but stars close to them.
Make sure sure the finder scope is properly aligned - use the moon for that - and then try again.